# How to delete data from Angular Firestore by Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing some problems with deleting the data from firestore by using Angular 8 but not getting success. Below is my code for Angular 8 and my collection.

```js
public DeleteMyOrder(ProductModel: ProductDModel)
{
    this.registerCollection = this
        .afs
        .collection('FarmerInfo')
        .doc('Orders')
        .collection('OrderInfo', ref => {
            return ref.where('CustomerNumber', '==', ProductModel.OrderID);
        });
}
```

`This.registerCollection.Delete()` not working in my case.

Comment: where are u deleting?

Comment: I am Trying "This.registerCollection.Delete()" to delete this document but its not working can you please guide me for correct deleting method in my case.

Comment: You are using angularfire inside that library there is a method called `delete()` which you are not using

Comment: I am using same but Delete  method is not there to delete collection... Can you please let guide me how can I delete this collection.. this.registerCollection=this.afs.collection('FarmerInfo').doc('Orders').collection('OrderInfo',ref =>{
    return ref.where('CustomerNumber','==',ProductModel.OrderID)
  });